# Easy_install of wxpython has "setup script" error

Tags: python, wxpython, easy-install

I have an install of python 2.5 that fink placed in /sw/bin/. I use the easy install command

```
sudo /sw/bin/easy_install wxPython
```

to try to install wxpython and I get an error while trying to process wxPython-src-2.8.9.1.tab.bz2 that there is not setup script. Easy-install has worked for several other installations until this one. Any help on why it's busting now?

EDIT: The error occurs before dumping back to shell prompt.

*Reading http://wxPython.org/download.php

Best match: wxPython src-2.8.9.1

Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-2.8.9.1.tar.bz2

Processing wxPython-src-2.8.9.1.tar.bz2 

error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-tNg6FG/wxPython-src-2.8.9.1.tar.bz2*

Comment: Could be a number of issues, can you update your question with 3 lines of text before and after the error.  Might be as simple as a failed/corrupted download?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple reason why it's busting: there just is no setup.py in wxPython; wxPython does not use distutils for installation.

Instead, read the file README.1st.txt in source distribution for instruction on how to install wxPython.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then why does easy_install have a recipe for wx? (Upvote because pasting the error message into google led me straight here.  Thanks for sharing.)

Answer (score 3):

**wxPython 2.8.9.1 does use distutils**

Under 'wxPython-src-2.8.9.1/wxPython/' run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

To install wxPython. At least that's what the INSTALL.txt says for that specific version.

Comment: Tried that. Got an error anyway:
In file included from src/helpers.cpp:16:
include/wx/wxPython/wxPython_int.h:19:10: fatal error: 'wx/wx.h' file not found
#include <wx/wx.h> :(